# Block whatsapp with firewall windows 10

Tags: whatsapp

I use the connection sharing of windows 10
how I can block the ports of whatsapp, and prohibit the video plays. with the windows firewall.

J'utilise la connection partager de windows 10
comment, je peux bloquer les ports de whatsapp, et interdire les lectures vidéo. avec le firewall de windows

Comment: Voting to close as this isn't a programming question. Ask general computer questions on Super User instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may block domain, ip's and ports

**IP's**:
https://www.whatsapp.com/cidr.txt

**Ports**:

- TCP 5222
- TCP 5223
- TCP 5228
- TCP 5242

**Domains** ([How to block a domain w/ Windows Firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/270524/blocking-web-sites-with-windows-firewall)):

- whatsapp.com
- whatsapp.net

Comment: How can I block domaine?

Comment: @william Check my answer again, accept it if you think it's correct.